# How can I create local user in oracle 12c using oracle sql developer and also login to pluggable dataabase using oracle sql develper

Tags: oracle

I have installed oracle 12c on windows 10 with following information as under:
Global database name        : orcl
Oracle system identifier(sid): orcl
Create as Container database
Pluggable database name : pdborcl
and 
Password for all Accounts Sys, system, dbsnmp, pdbadmin
password: Oracle12345